# JavaScript / jQuery "Uncaught TypeError" classList

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class

i've searcherd for answers but i didn't find nothing.. so please if you think this is a duplicate tell me and i'll remove it, thanks.

When i write something like `body.classList.add("someExampleClass");` the console gives me that `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined`. I've added the CDN

> //cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/classlist/2014.01.31/classList.min.js

but it keeps the error, i've tried with Chrome and Safari.

That's the full code:

HTML

```
  <svg height="35" width="35" id="rect1" class="" onmouseover="over()">
      <rect width="35" height="35"/>
  </svg>
```

JS

```
function over() {
  $('p').classList.add("purple");
}
```

Thanks in advance to all and have a good day.

Comment: You need $('p').addClass("purple") ?

Comment: I do not see any `p`-tag in your HTML. When do you call your `over()` function? Maybe `classList`-js is not loaded yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try this:

```
$('p')[0].classList.add("purple");
```

or this:

```
$('p').addClass("purple");
```

Answer (score 1):

classList is a DOM property. So your code should be,

```
$('p')[0].classList.add("purple");
```

Or

```
 $('p').get(0).classList.add("purple");
```

`$('p')` is a jquery object, get() will convert it as dom object.

Or you can simply use,

```
$('p').addClass("purple")
```